# Is Flyp.me legit

Tags: exchanges

I frequently use [shapeshift](https://shapeshift.io) to convert from bitcoin to many other currencies. Today I found the site [ExchangeCompare.io](https://exchangecompare.io/) that comapres shapeshift exchange rates to it's competitors.

For larger amounts (~1 BTC) I saw that a site called [flyp.me](https://flyp.me) is the cheapest.
Honestly I never heard of them and I'm a bit afraid trusting them with my money. Does anybody have ever used them? Can I trust this site?